# How to silently connect?

Tags: android, sockets, java-native-interface

I'm sorry for that question but my device is broken and I'm working with the emulator for now.
I need to make a silent connection, i.e. without any prompt to the user. I understand that there is some class for connecting to a wireless access point. So after I have established a connection:
1) If I open a Socket will it prompt the user?
2) If I open a socket with JNI will it prompt the user?

Thanks,
Nahum

Comment: So your device is broken, huh? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening a socket will not prompt the user under any normal circumstances. Once your app has the appropriate permissions it doesn't matter if you open the socket from Java or using JNI.